# Installing ruby on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ubuntu, github, ssh

I am trying to install Ruby in Ubuntu 13.04. For that I have followed the instruction at http://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu#ruby. But after executing the statement **ssh -T git@github.com**
I am always getting the message "Permission Denied(Public Key)". I have no idea how to fix that. Can anyone please help me to fix this problem? Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you either didn't generate your key properly or you didn't copy it into github properly.

Comment: This is a "connecting to github" problem, has nothing to do with ruby.

Comment: http://bit.ly/12PtLCB

Answer (score 4):

there are perfectly legitimate reasons to install ruby differently,
but you do not mention that you would like to do something other than the default.

the default way to install ruby on ubuntu would be to install this package:
http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/ruby

you can do so by running

```
sudo apt-get install ruby
```

when installing the package, at no point you should come to a situation like the one mentioned in your question.

Comment: Yes Sir, I have not followed that approach.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate ssh keys and import them to your github account.
Check https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys